# Comparing Record from First Record - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following with the data using Jupyter Python

```
DATE    UNIQUE  EMAL    TOTAL   DECISION_1  DECISION_2  SCORE
12/15/18    abcde01 abc@hotmail.com 100 A   D   10
12/15/19    abcde02 abc@gmail.com   200 D   A   20
12/15/20    abcde03 abc@outlook.com 300 D   A   30
12/15/21    abcde01 abc@hotmail.com 100 A   D   10
12/15/22    abcde01 abc@hotmail.com 200 D   A   20
12/15/23    abcde02 abc@gmail.com   400 A   D   30
12/15/24    abcde03 abc@outlook.com 300 D   D   40
```

I am trying to grab the first ever record of the unique users and comparing it to every try they ever did and decision outcomes and displaying the results.

For example:
I would maybe select if Decision was ever "A" and decision changed to "D"

Showing that abcde01 A then A then D

and somehow displaying it numerically or showing that they have changed their decision

this my be vague as I just started in data and am also struggling at what this might be called in terms of googling it and also displaying the results, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please elaborate the problem. The problem definition is unclear. Add some sample record from the data, and a more clear objective.

Comment: Can you see the sample data now?

Comment: Yes, I can see the data now but it is still unclear as to what you're trying to achieve.